# Find the closest coordinates in a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a simple script that needs to find the users current zipcode by their location.  I have a massive database of all the zipcodes with their coordinates.  I need to find the closest zipcode to their location.  The site is a wordpress site so I am using their functions.

I have tried the following code but it is not accurate enough. It is off by about 15-20 miles and picks the wrong zipcode.

```
$SQL = $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT zip, ( abs(lat - %d) + abs(lon - %d) ) as distance ".
    "FROM {$wpdb->prefix}zipcodes ORDER BY distance LIMIT 1",
    $data['lat'], $data['lon']
);
$closest = $wpdb->get_results( $SQL );
```

Comment: Do you have access to this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html#function_st-distance-sphere

Comment: I am not sure how would I form a statement for it?

Comment: If you'll provide some details about your tables, prefereable with some sample information, I'll see if I can provide a sample implementation.

Comment: Even if you pretend the earth is flat, the latitude and longitude numbers are not evenly spaced. One goes from -180 to 180, and the other from -90 to 90.

Comment: Also, if we were pretending the earth was flat, then it would be `sqrt (  (x1-x0)^2 - (y1-y0)^2 )` to get the planar distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have v5.7+, then you can use ST_Distance_Sphere:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html#function_st-distance-sphere

I'm going to guess at an implementation in a fiddle.  Take a look at this.  These are random zips, and I just picked a random zip to calculate distance from.  I didn't adjust your php code, because it looks like you know how to prepare a statement already, so I'm just providing the SQL.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a851a6539bfd5028c53cf5ad0e1a1f1f

```
SELECT zip, lon, lat, 
  ST_Distance_Sphere(
    POINT(-86.558882, 34.668212), POINT (lon, lat)
  ) as dist
FROM zipcodes ORDER BY 4 DESC;
```

where the arguments to POINT are (lon, lat).

Here is the POINT reference:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-point-property-functions.html

Let me know if this helps.

---

For future reference, you can find the CREATE statements for your table in the mysql editor (or you can get them from the command line if you need to, but who is using the command line?).  If you give those and an INSERT statement with some sample data in your question, along with the expected outcomes, that will give people more insight into your problem.  Also, provide your sql version and engine, since some things are engine and version specific.

You can also set up a fiddle with those statements to give people a headstart, but you should also include the statements and data themselves in the question, just in case the fiddle site goes down.

See this discussion on minimum reproducible examples for SQL questions:

[Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: zip = zipcode, lat = latitude, lon = longitude, id = id;  simple layout;

Comment: @james, just edited the answer to include a fiddle and some reference.

Comment: People will downvote questions without details a lot quicker than when I started, it seems.  Theoretically I think you're supposed to remove your downvote if the deficiency is corrected, but in practice I don't think downvoters are monitoring all those posts to see if they get edited.  Just make sure you include the basic information people need to help you, not so much to avoid the downvote, although it will help, but mostly so that people will be able to help you.  A lot of people will just skip right over questions that don't have the MRE.